# Using multiple OnEdits

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, javascript-objects, triggers

so I'm trying to combine a few onEdits with specific criteria but am struggling.  I am new to this, but I received some help previously and was able to create OnEdits that will go to different designated tabs from the same sheet.

However, now I am trying to keep that functionality, but also add in the ability to add multiple OnEdits from ANOTHER sheet.

For example - Columns checked on the master tab would go to export 1 and 2, while the columns checked from a separate tab (master2 would) go to tabs named export 3 and 4.  So basically - two separate onEdits starting from two different tabs rather than one.

Is this possible? Here's what I tried, but I am super off.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry' + JSON.stringify(e));
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "master" && e.value=="TRUE") {
    if(e.range.columnStart==4) {
      //e.source.toast('Flag1');
      var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("export1");
      var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1);
    }
    if(e.range.columnStart==5) {
      //e.source.toast('Flag2');
      var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("export2");
      var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1);
    }
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).copyTo(trg)
   if(sh.getName() == "master2" && e.value=="TRUE") {
    if(e.range.columnStart==4) {
      //e.source.toast('Flag1');
      var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("export3");
      var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1); 
     }
}
```

Comment: The answer is probably yes. But your to have provide more details.

Comment: Thanks @Cooper - I basically have two separate tabs.  I don't want to combine the data because it is unrelated.  Off one tab, I'd like to make it so a checked box in column 4 on that tab will send to a tab called "export1". Then, using a different master sheet "master2", I would like to have a bunch of columns with checkboxes, so if any of them were to be checked, that row would go to different tabs.  Each column would get it's own tab, so there would be 10 hidden tabs that get the info whenever the aligned checkbox is clicked

Answer (score 0):

I presume this is what you're looking for:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry' + JSON.stringify(e));
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  //master
  if(sh.getName() == "master" && e.value=="TRUE") {
    if(e.range.columnStart==4) {
      //e.source.toast('Flag1');
      var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("export1");
      var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1);
    }
    if(e.range.columnStart==5) {
      //e.source.toast('Flag2');
      var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("export2");
      var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1);
    }
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).copyTo(trg);
  }
  //master2
  if(sh.getName()=="master2" && e.value=="TRUE") {
    if(e.range.columnStart==4) {
      //e.source.toast('Flag1');
      var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("export3");
      var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1); 
    }
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).copyTo(trg)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Cooper - that's exactly what I'm looking for!! I was trying to piece that together earlier.  It looks like I'm still having an issue though -- I am receiving this issue when trying to save the code you created: SyntaxError: Unexpected token } (line 17, file "Code.gs")

Any ideas? Thanks again, I know I am terrible at all of this but trying to learn! I tried deleting the bracket in line 17, but no luck there either.

Comment: Sorry I had a comma instead of semicolon at the end of a line.

Comment: Wow! Works like a charm - you are a genius my friend! Thanks so much @Cooper